# Azure API Management - Optional Parameters

Tags: azure, liquid, azure-api-management

I'm trying to work with optional Query parameters. But when I try to access this parameter in my body mapping to my backend SOAP service, I get no results.

I defined the parameter like this.
[image: Query parameters]

And I'm trying to access it in my Liquid template with this code.

```
{{context.Request.Url.Query.GetValueOrDefault("test","false")}}
```

But the result is just empty. Could somebody help me to find what I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `context.Request.OriginalUrl` instead.  OriginalUrl is what comes into the Gateway. `context.Request.Url` is after it has been rewritten for the backend.

Comment: I just tried this, but it's still empty in my request message. {{context.Request.OriginalUrl.Query.GetValueOrDefault("test","false")}} Strange thing is, when I put a trace on the same parameter just before my set-body, I can get a value. But when I try to access it in the set-body, then it's empty. Even if I put it in a variable first.

Comment: @TimD'haeyer  Ahhh, I see the issue.  Unfortunately Liquid binding and C# expressions don't work the same way.  What you are doing is a C# expression that needs to go inside  `@(...)` or `@{...}`  Unfortunately we couldn't duplicate that syntax inside Liquid templates, as Liquid binding only supports accessing arrays and maps.  You are supposed to be able to do `{{ context.Request.OriginalUrl.Query.test[0] }}` but it is currently not working for me.  I'm investigating why.

Comment: @TimD'haeyer Whoa, that's awesome, now to figure out what I was doing wrong!!

Comment: @TimD'haeyer If this binding breaks on you, that's my fault.  There was a regression in the latest build. That's why it wasn't working for me!  A hotfix is going out today.